# WebElement, isDisplayed doesn't work correctly

Tags: selenium-webdriver

So, I try to call 'isDisplayed' method of WebElement. That element has a parent with css propperty 'width' equals '0px' and 'overflow' equals 'hidden'. Element itself is not visible, of course, but method 'isDisplayed' returns true. It MUST return false! How can I send this bug to developers?

```
<label>
    <span class="before"> // width: 0px; overflow:hidden;
        &nbsp;
        <span>Yes</span> // invisible element
    </span>
    <i></i>
    <span class="after">
        <span>No</span>
    </span>
</label>
```

Code of java:

```
WebElement sw = node.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[text()='Yes']")); // node is selected by other query
sw.isDisplayed() //result is true
```

Comment: could you post the complete element selector you are using and element's HTML-code?

Comment: So what have you tried? Putting "selenium+bugs" into Google, the very **first** link is https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/list

Answer (score 0):

You could use the javascript executor to determine if an element is visible, which will take CSS styling into account. You'll need to be able to come up with a reliable CSS selector for the element though

C# solution...

```
string script = "return $('.before span').is(':visible')"

var executor = WebDriver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
var result = executor.ExecuteScript(script);
```

Comment: Most funny thing is that incorrectly too... Surprise, surprise! JQuery call method jQuery.expr.filters.visible and that !hidden(), like this. And then it exams only css property 'display'. I think, I'll write this realization myself if nobody can do IT.